# C++ Program Displaying The Names Of The Array Indexes Which I Cleared Using String Function?

Tags: c++

This is the code of my Practice Task, i'm having a little bit problem in it, my code runs perfectly but the problem is, the function: `del_book()` which is used to delete a specific book in my program, so if i delete a book or many books, it still displays this:

```
Book id:
Book Title:
Book author:
Book price:
```

it's deleting the elements but it's still displaying all this. So can anyone help me in this.
Here's the code...

**...c++**

```
void del_book(book volume[5])
    {
        string name;
        cout << "enter the name of the book which you want to delete" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (name == volume[i].book_title)
            {
                volume[i].book_id.clear();
                volume[i].book_title.clear();
                volume[i].book_author.clear();
                volume[i].price.clear();
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << "book deleted!" << endl;
    }

    void disp_all(book volume[5])
    {
        cout << "\n=====================\ndisplaying all books\n=====================" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << "book no." << i + 1 << endl;
            cout << "book id: " << volume[i].book_id << endl;
            cout << "book title: " << volume[i].book_title << endl;
            cout << "book author: " << volume[i].book_author << endl;
            cout << "book price: " << volume[i].price << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: Sometimes you are using `getline()` for `book_title`, sometimes `cin >> `. Looks suspicious.

Comment: That's cuz when i use getline multiple times, it ignores the first character on ouput, it's cuz i used cin.ignore(), but if i don't use ignore function it'll add a new line during user input, so i can't be able to add book title on second iteration.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What I wanted to point out is that you use `getline` in `add_book()` when reading `book_title`, but you use `cin >> name` in `del_book` and you are comparing `name` with `book_title`. Due to this you will not delete a book with title containing whitespace.

Comment: Without knowing what parts of C++ you already know or are allowed to use, it is hard to give you a perfect answer. Insread of using an array, one would normally use an STL container (vector for starters) here. A vector's length doesn't have to be constant like your array's length. So you can actually remove elements from it instead of just setting them to empty strings.

Comment: Alternatively as a fast fix, you could detect if the book_id has size 0 and then not display the book.

Comment: The last if in search_disp_book is certainly not right and the second for loop in update_book as well.

Comment: @Paul You're right, but i'm currently learning the oop section of C++. My task was to perform this with basic c++. I don't know about STL...

Comment: Then you use that small fix. If you say that a valid book always has a non-empty ID, you can skip books with book_id.size() == 0 when displaying books. You may want to warn the user if he tries to add/update a book with an empty ID.

Comment: How should i do this, can u please write it down for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your problem is that you clear all the string but not eliminate the element in the array**, in this way the `disp_all(book volume[5])` function retrive ever 5 elements.

A possible solution is verify before print the element if the name of the book is not equal to an empty string.

Another more useful solution is use one of the standard container of standard library.
For example you can use a `std::list` or `std::map` for store e retrive book collection.
So when you need to delete an item you can use the utility of the container used.